# Is possible to approximate to a grammar in an iterative way?

Tags: xml, xsd, grammar

Many tools can generate an XSD grammar from an XML example.

Normally the output of such tools has to be tuned by hand.

My question is if it is possible to do this process in an iterative way.
I mean, Instead of giving 1 XML example, to give a bunch of examples and after each iteration the XSD schema is refined.

I don't know any system which has this capability.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I think I have to clarify some points. I know that XMLspy can generate a grammar from an example. I am using it. (actually in the old SGML time a system called Fred could do it). Normally this grammar is pretty primitive, although all the options that XMLspy gives you for the creation. I have many thousands of xml files which are machine-generated, all of them quite similar. That is, all of them have the same structure. If you can define a "distance" between all of them is minimal.
I am looking for a system which generates a unique (minimal) grammar which accepts every file I gave for its generation.
I can imagine that such a system can take the first example, generate a grammar, take the second, refine the generated grammar for the previous example, and so on until the last XML input file.

Answer (score 3):

[QTAssistant](http://www.paschidev.com) (I am associated with it) has the ability to take in more than one XML file, and generate an XSD out of it.

v4.x

[image]

v5.x

[image]

Caveats:

- you need to register to download the free evaluation.
- XSDs generated by a tool, through an inference mechanism, are bound to need manual intervention. For large XSDs, we typically refactor at least the type definitions and/or elements, depending on customer's preference re: authoring styles (type-based vs. element-based), since the output tends to be rather nested.
- I am a bit unclear by what you mean with `to give a bunch of examples and after each iteration the XSD schema is refined` ; I'll explain how it works, and you take it from there... After invoking the command, you get a standard open file dialog, where you get to select one or more XML files. Once selected, you are prompted for a folder where the XSD files (could be more than one) are going to be generated. The outcome is a set of XSD files that are to successfully validate ALL the XML files you have provided as input.

If by `iteration` you meant the approach where one takes in an existing (model) XSD that is then to be extended/altered to comply with the selected XMLs, basically feeding XML files one by one or in groups, then this tool will not work; the tool recreates the XSDs from scratch, based solely on the selected XMLs.

Answer (score 2):

Many tools (including [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html), [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/), and [Petru's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886533/petru-gardea) excellent [QTAssistant](http://www.paschidev.com/)) can generate an XSD from a single XML document instance, but I do not know of any tools that will iteratively refine an XSD given multiple XML document instances.  However, yes, it would be possible and productive to use the knowledge of multiple instances to refine the grammar.

It would be helpful for resolving ambiguity in several areas where one cannot determine a grammar from a single instance.  For example, each of the following could be better approximated given a diverse sample of valid documents:

- Requiredness
- Cardinality
- Choice
- Type

Why hasn't such a tool been built?  I suspect that the need for a rough XSD that covers a single XML document instance is just so much more common of a use case.  It helps for getting started writing the first cut of an XSD.  It provides a good enough source for code generators such as JAXB.  Finally, it's highly likely that hands-on refinement will still be needed even if a better approximation could be attained through automated refinement based on multiple XML document instances anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, I agree. It would be nice to have something like what you/we are describing.